# How should I understand "short of " in this sentence?

Tags: phrases

I learned the following sentence from *The Economist* (December 3rd-9th 2011).

... The implications seemed nothing **short of** revolutionary.

I've looked it up at [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/short%20of) online dictionary. It is said that it means "of a lesser degree than". What's the function of this phrase here? How should I understand this sentence?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Nothing short of" is a common idiom.

"Short of", as you found, means "of a lesser degree than".

"Nothing short of" means "not at all of a lesser degree than".

"Nothing short of revolutionary" means "I am not exaggerating when I say this is revolutionary". It might indicate that the writer feels that if they merely wrote "revolutionary" on its own, the word would not have enough impact.

Answer (score 4):

It means exactly as the dictionary says.

```
short of = lesser than
```

... The implications seemed nothing **less than** revolutionary.

Or in other words,

The implications seemed quite revolutionary

The preceding use of "nothing" makes it a negative of "less than"

Comment: @shinynewbilke, thanks. I thought it means "the implications seemed not revolutionary at all"．`:-)`

Answer (score 1):

You can read it replacing part of the idiom with *but* to quickly get an idea:

> The implications seemed nothing ***but*** revolutionary.

see:
President Barack Obama says the savage storms that swept through the South are nothing short of 'catastrophic.'  [They are as bad as catastrophic.]

Comment: I like your example. `:)`